# Minimum height in split rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a split rectangle node, and I would like either for the entire node to be a certain height, with the splits spread equally, or each nodepart to be a certain height. I have the following code, in which only the first part is stretched, how can I apply this to all nodeparts?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    rect/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=4,
        draw=black,
        rounded corners, 
        text width=7cm,
        text height=3cm
    }]  


    % Split Rectangle
    \node [rect] {
        First Item
        \nodepart{two} Second Item
        \nodepart{three} $\vdots$
        \nodepart{four}  Last Item
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the manual page 450, *When split vertically, the rectangle split will observe any `minimum width` requirements but any `minimum height` will be ignored.* But you can use `inner sep`, not so useful though. If necessary, switch to `matrix` node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
  \def\mystrut{\vrule height 1.5cm depth 1.5cm width 0pt} 

 \begin{document}    

   \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    rect/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=4,
        draw=black,
        rounded corners
    }]  


    % Split Rectangle
    \node [rect] {
      \mystrut  First Item
        \nodepart{two}\mystrut Second Item
        \nodepart{three} $\vdots$
        \nodepart{four} \mystrut Last Item
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in the section of your code after `% Split Rectangle`, when I add `\centerline{......} \centerline{........}` after `\nodepart{one} \mystrut`, it will only modify the height of the box around the first line instead of the entire `\nodepart{one}`, how can I fix it?