# Alignment of tikz nodes in a chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

How can the north anchors of the nodes in a going to the right chain be aligned in a `tikz` picture?

As can be demonstrated by the following example, by default they seem to be aligned by the center anchor.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains,}

\tikzset{
  token/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split part fill={cyan!25,yellow!50},
    rectangle split ignore empty parts,
    draw,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,node distance=1mm]
  \node[on chain,token] {TWhile};
  \node[on chain,token] {TLParen};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}ip};
  \node[on chain,token] {TEq};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}z};
  \node[on chain,token] {TRParen};
  \node[on chain,token] {TPlusPlus};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}ip};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the given document:]

Comment: I believe you are looking for `start chain=going base right`. Actually using the `north` anchor would need a different implementation of the `<direction>=of <another node>` key options. The `right` in `going right` means that the `west` anchor from a new node is placed `right=of \tikzchainprevious` which means right of `\tikzchainprevious.east` (if `on grid=false`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, maybe you want to make an answer from your comment.

Comment: I have posted an answer, though I added some more discussion and ideas that can be helpful (hopefully).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are actually not aligned by the center anchor (but the center anchor do lie on one straight line as the `center` anchor is at the same height as the `west` and the `east` anchors).

The `right` in `going right` means that the `west` anchor from a new node is placed `right=of \tikzchainprevious` which means right of `\tikzchainprevious.east` (see reference 1).

Besides the obvious directions like for example `above` and `below right`, there also exist `mid left|right` and `base left|right` which uses the `mid|base west|east` anchors respectively. These anchors are dependent from the actual text line containing the first part node (or the only one). The difference is only a vertical shift as the `mid` anchors are simply `.5ex` above their `base` counter parts.

With `start chain=going base right`, you’ll get:

[image]

This looks weird because:

- the only `q` is the only letter in the blue boxes that has a depth. I recommend using either

  - `text depth=+0pt`, or

    [image]
  - `text depth=\depthof{q}`.

    [image]

For the yellow boxes I’d apply `font=\vphantom{i}` and `\smash`ing the `p`. Sadly, the keys `text depth` and `text height` do not affect node parts (they values aren’t considered at all), you can also use `font=\vphantom{ip}` to get something similar to `text depth=\depthof{q}` for the main node text:

[image]

Another, rather easy solution would be to use `font=\strut` for every part:

[image]

---

If one wants to actually use the north anchors (or rather the `north east` and `north west` anchors), one can add:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{north left/.code =\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north east}{-1}{0}{north west}{1}}
\tikzset{north right/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{1}{0}{north east}{1}}
\tikzset{south left/.code =\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south east}{-1}{0}{south west}{1}}
\tikzset{south right/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south west}{1}{0}{south east}{1}}

\tikzset{west above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south west}{0}{1}{north west}{1}}
\tikzset{west below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{0}{-1}{south west}{1}}
\tikzset{east above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south east}{0}{1}{north east}{1}}
\tikzset{east below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north east}{0}{-1}{south east}{1}}
\makeatother
```

and use it with `start chain=going north right`. It doesn’t make a difference in this case because all nodes have the same (text) height.

They can be used to top-/bottom-/left-/right-align nodes while placing them in a row. (This works best for rectangular node shapes.)
For example, using `start chain=going south right` creates:

[image]

#### Reference

1. [Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386/16595) (It’s about the `positioning` library.)
2. [TikZ multipart nodes: How to set text attributes (opacity) for some/all parts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57536/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains}
\tikzset{
  token/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split part fill={cyan!25,yellow!50},
    rectangle split ignore empty parts,
    draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=going base right,
  node distance=1mm,
  every on chain/.append style={
%    font=\strut,
    text depth=+0pt,
    every two node part/.append style={
      font=\strut,
      font=\vphantom{i}
    }
  }
  ]
  \node[on chain,token] {TWhile};
  \node[on chain,token] {TLParen};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}i\smash{p}};
  \node[on chain,token] {TEq};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}z};
  \node[on chain,token] {TRParen};
  \node[on chain,token] {TPlusPlus};
  \node[on chain,token] {TId\nodepart{two}i\smash{p}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```