# Jump to different anchor in \draw chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, anchor

Sometimes chaining `\draw` commands comes in handy for me, e.g., in the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm}
]
\draw 
node[box] (ui) {+}
+(0,-1.5) node[box] {+}
++(3,0) node[box, scale=1.5] (helyOS) {+}
+(0, -1.5) node[box] {+};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example]

I understand the boxes have `center` anchoring. But how could I *jump* to another anchor before moving on with the `+(x,y)` or `++(x,y)` provided without defining node names manually or assuming heights/widths?

This would be helpful, e.g., to draw lines between `(ui.east)` and `(helyOS.west)`.

Probably something like `\draw node[box] {+} ++(goto node.south) ++(0,-1);`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119445/alignment-of-tikz-nodes-in-a-chain

Answer (score 1):

Hm, if I understand you correctly, you like to have something this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm}
                    ]
\draw   node[box] (ui) {+}
    +(0,-1.5) node[box] {+}
    ++(3,0) node[box, scale=1.5,anchor=south] (helyOS) {+} % <--- added anchor
    +(0, -1.5) node[box] {+};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, default anchor is center of node, but you can change it by `anchor=...`, for example to `anchor=north` or `anchor=south west`, etc.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Actually I wanted to keep the `center` anchor for positioning of node `(helyOS)` but jump to its south anchor before applying `+(0,-1.5)`

Comment: @F1iX, than ask package author for new version of TikZ, which will comply with your wish.