# How to connect nodes using \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

[image]I’m trying to draw a structure like that in Latex and I’m having a hard time. I know how to draw nodes using `\node` and how to draw arcs using `\draw` but I can’t connect the two.

Comment: This is very confusing. What is the `node` package you're talking about? The output you provided is very straightforward in Ti*k*Z. What did you try yet?

Comment: I think you could pick one of the solution you received and accept it, now ;)

Answer (score 9):

In order to help you starting with Ti*k*Z, here's a quick solution that reproduce your hand drawn design. Feel free to adapt it.

In the future, please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

[image: nodes on chain]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain=going base right,
        node distance=2cm,
        every on chain/.append style=
            {draw = violet,
            circle,
            inner sep=0pt,
            minimum size=1cm,
            line width=1pt,
            font=\sffamily},
        myedge/.style={line width=1pt, violet}]
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
            \node[on chain] (\i) {\i};
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}
            \draw[myedge] (\i) -- (\j);
            }
        
        \draw[myedge]   (1) to [out=90, in=0] ++(-2,3)
                        (2) to [out=90, in=180] ++(2,3)
                        (3) to [out=90, in=90, looseness=1.5] (4)
                        (5) to [out=90, in=180] ++(2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to latex and I didn't even know how to properly phrase my problem but that's exactly the structure I want. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 for  `start chain = going base right,`!

Comment: Where you find definition for `start chain = going base right`?  I made some experiments with it but so far didn't find and diference to `start chain = going right`

Comment: I found it a while ago in an example here on TeX-SX for a chain of `rectangle split` nodes with vertical split. This allowed nodes to be chained on the first split cell instead of the centers. Here it's useless. Try adding `\node[on chain, text width=1cm] {NOW YOU KNOW};` right after your chain of nodes and you'll see.

Comment: @Zarko: [I talked about this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119583/204164).

Comment: @SebGlav, thank you very much. Unfortunately this option is not documented in documentation ...

Answer (score 5):

A wee bit variation of nice @SebGlaw answer:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2cm, on grid, 
  start chain = going right,   %
vertex/.style = {circle, draw = blue, thick,
                 minimum size=1em, 
                 font=\sffamily,
                 on chain, join = by arr},
   arr/.style = {draw=blue, semithick},                        
                        ]                        ]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\node[vertex] (\i) {\i};

\draw[arr]  (1) edge [out=90, in=0]   ++(-2,3)
            (2) edge [out=90, in=180] ++( 2,3)
            (3) edge [out=90, in=90,
                      min distance=15mm] (4)
            (5) edge [out=90, in=180] ++(2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer too, especially `on chain, join` which I didn't use.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way a beginner might approach this:

[image]

First, place the nodes at your desired coordinates using the `\node` command. Then use `\draw` to connect nodes as you wish. The `to[out= , in=]` describes the angle out and the angle in to get curved lines. Finally, `++(x,y)` describes relative coordinates (right `x`, up `y`) from the node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw=blue, thick, inner sep=5pt}]
\node at (2,0)(A1){1};
\node at (4,0)(A2){2};
\node at (6,0)(A3){3};
\node at (8,0)(A4){4};
\node at (10,0)(A5){5};
\node at (12,0)(A6){6};
\draw[thick, blue] (A1)--(A2)--(A3)--(A4)--(A5)--(A6) 
    (A3) to[out=90, in=90] (A4)
    (A1) to[out=90, in=0] ++(-1,2)
    (A2) to[out=90, in=180] ++(1,2)
    (A5) to[out=90, in=180] ++(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.